# How to solve the "package 'NCmisc' is not available" error?

Tags: r, linux, package

I recently used Zorin lunix and R (version 3.6.3).
I encountered a problem when using the renv::install() function.

The error is that the 'NCmisc' package is not available.
Can anyone help me?

I have already changed the repositories [setRepositories()] in the session but the error persists.

Comment: have you reviewed the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa) yet ... ?

Comment: As far as I can tell `NCmisc` doesn't suffer from any of the obvious problems: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NCmisc/index.html . Since Zorin Linux is based on Ubuntu, probably the easiest thing to do would be to follow the instructions [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) to update your version of R (3.6.3 is 3 years old, which is ancient by R standards ...)

Comment: Thank you. I will follow the instructions!

Comment: What exactly did you change the repositories to when you called `setRepositories`? Were you getting an error before you tried to change the repositories? Or what made you decide to call that function?